# '=' and '(' are bypassed XSS

Tags: xss

How can I add `=` in my script when `return input.replace (/ [= (] /g, '');` is replacing it? This is only for education purpose solving CTF. Used HTML codes but not working.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what you’re asking. What does the script in question do?

Comment: My guess is try different encodings, octal escape,  e.g. `String.fromCharCode(075)` or  \u003d.  You could eval the entire code you want to run if you escape when pasting, and unescape during execution.

Comment: return '<input type="text" value="' + input + '">';
return input.replace(/[=(]/g, '');
used this string <BODY ONLOAD&#61;"prompt&#&40;1)"> In place  of  <BODY ONLOAD="prompt(1)">

Comment: Yes Tried encoding, Not working... The escape sequence has this code return '<input type="text" value="' + input + '">';
return input.replace(/[=(]/g, '');
used this string <BODY ONLOAD&#61;"prompt&#&40;1)"> In place  of  <BODY ONLOAD="prompt(1)">

Answer (score 4):

```
  = =
```

For clarity, that is:

```
[space][space]=[space]=[space]
```

The reason this works is because there's only one replace pass running on the input string. In this original string, there's only one instance of "[space]=[space]". When it's removed, there's now a new instance of "[space]=[space]" left over, but replace only scans through the string left-to-right once.

This technique is general to cases where replace is used once to remove a string from another string. Consider the code `input.replace(/blue/g, '')`. If you gave the string "my favorite color is blblueue", the inner "blue" will be removed, leaving just "my favorite color is blue".

Comment: Nope It's not working

Comment: @user192776 - 2 things. First of all - if it's not working because of some other issue elsewhere then this answer has addressed the question, so you may need to ask a new question. Secondly - 'not working' is useless on stackexchange, what do you mean 'not working'? Give details.

Comment: In case blblueue we are not giving blue directly anywhere and with [space][space]=[space]=[space], I am giving equals sign direclty as = sign is globally replaced it's replacing even in this scenario. Tried all sort HTML encoding and when = sign is replaced it's not prompting

Comment: `input.replace (/ [= (] /g, '');` returns ` = ` for the input I gave, so I don't understand your comments. Maybe you didn't post all the relevant code.

Comment: But it replacing = sign, And those are the only instructions, and <svg> <script>prompt&#40;1);</script></svg> this worked. Thank you everyone for responding

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML encoding with svg tags, After encoding it's not valid javascript. svg renders it text try within svg tags